# Как полностью передать модель в метод?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

я передаю модель в представление, там его изменяю, и отправляю в метод `Correct_post`, дальше в метод, который записывает данные в базу данных, однако `Article` возвращается с `id = 0`, хотя изначально он был другим, из-за этого я не могу сохранить `Article` в ДБ. Где ошибка?

Article:

```
public class Article
{
    public Int64 Id;
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public String HtmlText { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public String BigPicPath { get; set; }
    public String SmallPicPath { get; set; }
}
```

`News.CorrectArticle`:

```
public static void CorrectArticle(Article a)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("News_updateArticle", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
    Random rnd = new Random();

    cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = a.Id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NText);
    cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = a.Name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@HtmlText", SqlDbType.NText);
    cmd.Parameters["@HtmlText"].Value = a.HtmlText;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = a.Date;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SmallPicPath", SqlDbType.NText);
    cmd.Parameters["@SmallPicPath"].Value = a.SmallPicPath;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { throw e; }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Correct(int id)
{
    if (isAdmin(Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"]))
    {
        return View(News.GetArticleById(id));
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
[HttpPost, ActionName("Correct")]
public ActionResult Correct_post(Article model)
{
    if (isAdmin(Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"]))
    {
        News.CorrectArticle(model);
        return RedirectToAction("NewsList");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Razor code:

```
@model SiteShop.Models.News.Article
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Correct";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<a href="/Admin/Create">Отчистить</a>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>BlogPost</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BigPicPath)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BigPicPath)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BigPicPath)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SmallPicPath)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SmallPicPath)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SmallPicPath)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HtmlText)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HtmlText)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HtmlText)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        </p>

        <p>

            Posted Content : @Html.Raw(ViewBag.HtmlContent)
        </p>

    </fieldset>

}
```

Comment: у вас `Html.BeginForm()` пустой. а должен быть что-то вроде `Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`

Comment: @Stack, что так, что иначе, ничего не меняется, все данные есть, но отсутствует значение id(точнее 0), хотя оно равно 1498513324

Comment: @Stack раз метод есть и не отмечен атрибутом [Obsolete] - значит, его можно применять. Значения по умолчанию хорошо подходят для таких случаев, как у автора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Необходимо модифицировать исходный класс `Article` в частности поле `Id` необходимо преобразовать в свойство: `public Int64 Id {get;set;}`
2. Добавьте в свое представление `Correct` скрытое поле в котором будет храниться `Id`: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)`

тогда в метод пост который будет обрабатывать Вашу измененную модель вернется модель с `Id`

Comment: Увы, но это не помогло

Comment: @max619 сделайте поле `id` свойством

Comment: спасибо это помогло

Answer (score 1):

У вас Id был нулевым причине того что он является Label который преобразуется ViewEngine  как span, когда происходит post запрос то он отправляет на action только поля `<input>`. Вам нужно было его сделать как  `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)`